# How to check AppServiceConnection live status and Bring the app in running status if app has gone in suspended state

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Scenario :

I have opened an AppServiceConnection to UWP Application from other .net exe(window service). This triggers OnBackgroundActivated of App.xaml.cs of UWP App. Once OnBackgroundActivated execution finishes,then app goes into suspension state

Now, If Windows service want to send message via the same connection, then it goes into hang state and never returns as app is in suspended mode.

Is there any way to figure out if the app connection state is in suspended by AppServiceConnection object itself. Moreover, if App is in suspended mode, then bring the app in running state by using same connection object ?

I know I can bring app in running state by opening connection again.

But I am interested to know if I can bring the app in running with existing connection object only.

I have been through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/ almost through all the links but could not find anything of my use.

One option I can think of,On-suspended event send message to window service that App state is going to be suspended but somehow, I feel there has to be a better way for the same.

I have gone through the class members and it doesn't really offer such thing. 
It always returns status only when a new connection is opened.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, If Windows service want to send message via the same connection, then it goes into hang state and never returns as app is in suspended mode.

An app service can be implemented as a background task with  **Windows Runtime component project**, and can provide its service to other apps when app is in suspended mode. You could place all the processing logic in background task. For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).  And this is related [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices).